# Making Marker moving along line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, markers, animation

On a vector layer, I selected some points to make a polyline, and, let a Vertex Marker move along the polyline.

Now, I want to moving the marker smoothly between two points (means I need calculate points between two selected points), and, the marker's moving speed can be special, e.g: 5 km/h.

Is there any way to make these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) Animate tools. They seem to be doing something very similar to what you are looking for: interpolation of point positions between start and end point. If you have some programming skills, this would be a good point to start developing a solution specific to your requirements.